# Joomla site overrides Array.from() causing Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, google

I'm working on a custom Joomla module that has an input field, where users can start typing the name of a city and the field offers a list of cities using the Google Places autocomplete API.

The basic functionaly works fine, except that when the page loads I get the following JS error:

```
This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, which could cause Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly
```

I suspect that this error causes that I cannot further refine the google search results.

How could I figure out what part of my Joomla site overrides Array.from() and how could I fix this?

Thanks a lot, 
W.

Comment: I did a quick search and found stuff in media\system\js\mootools-core-uncompressed.js around line 133 in my joomla version. Is your site referencing mootools? I thought Joomla had relinquished using it on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm not aware of using mootools, but I'll do a more in-depth research for it. At the same time even with this error message I managed to achieve my goal with the the Google Places API, so it is not so pressing any more. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue - Google Maps doesn't like the combination of Mootools (enabled in my Template) and Progressive Cache (enabled in Joomla Global Config)

Luckily, I could disable Mootools in my Template